# Changing the schema of a parquet file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The current schema of my parquet file is:

```
scala> df.schema
org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructField(route,StringType,true), StructField(wgt,StringType,true))
```

And I would like to change it to the following and save and overwrite it in my HDFS:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructField(route,StringType,true), StructField(wgt,DoubleType,true))
```

I have no issue converting the schema to a DoubleType, but I'm having difficulty overwriting the file on my HDFS as the following error message keeps appearing:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://HDFS.../somefile.parquet/part-00000-6122bced-855d-4f64-b1c3-8a4d8090c580-c000.snappy.parquet
It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens because of Spark DAG workflow and its action operations.
You have to move your dataset to somewhere else and try to write it on the path you want